# How to use variables on different class with dart/flutter

Tags: dart

I have one class which is my getToken class. In this class ı get the token which is **String token**. Here is my **getToken.dart**

```
class GetToken {
  String token;
  Future<Null> getData() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.39:7070/api/v2/token";
    http.post(url, body: {
      "grant_type": "string",
      "branchcode": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "username": "string",
      "dbname": "string",
      "dbuser": "string",
      "dbpassword": "string",
      "dbtype": "string"
    }).then((response) {
      print("Response Status: ${response.statusCode}");
      //print("Response Body: ${response.body}");
      print('access token is -> ${json.decode(response.body)['access_token']}');
      token = json.decode(response.body)['access_token'];
    });
  }
}
```

I want to use this **token** in my getCari class and get the Json values in my rest api. Here is my **getCari.dart** class

```
class GetCari{
  getCari() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.39:7070/api/v2/ARPs",
    headers: {HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: token});

    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      return Cari.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else{
      throw Exception("Failed to Load");
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to ask how can ı use my token(which is get from getToken.dart) in my getCari.dart class. How can ı pass the token variable other classes?

Comment: you can use shared preference or you can make static variable, or you can send by navigator if you are switching to the other screen  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Dart's top level functions instead of classes which does not need instantiation.

This is mentioned in [Effective Dart documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members)

### token_manager.dart

```
String _token;
String get token => _token    // To ensure readonly

Future<Null> setToken() async {
  // set your _token here
}
```

### get_cari.dart

```
import 'token_manager.dart' as token_manager    // use your import path here

getCari() async {
  // You can now access token from token_manager from any class like this.
  final String token = token_manager.token;
}
```

### Excerpt

> In Java and C#, every definition must be inside a class, so it’s
>   common to see “classes” that exist only as a place to stuff static
>   members. Other classes are used as namespaces—a way to give a shared
>   prefix to a bunch of members to relate them to each other or avoid a
>   name collision.
>
> Dart has top-level functions, variables, and constants, so you don’t
>   need a class just to define something. If what you want is a
>   namespace, a library is a better fit. Libraries support import
>   prefixes and show/hide combinators. Those are powerful tools that let
>   the consumer of your code handle name collisions in the way that works
>   best for them.
>
> If a function or variable isn’t logically tied to a class, put it at
>   the top level. If you’re worried about name collisions, give it a more
>   precise name or move it to a separate library that can be imported
>   with a prefix.

Comment: Your token will be made available to other classes only after setToken promise resolves.

Comment: ı have an error get_cari.dart. "The getter token isn't defined for the class token_manager"

Comment: Did you add the getter `String get token => _token` to token_manager.dart?

Comment: Yes, ı was wrote String get token => _token to the token_manager.dart

Comment: Why does the error say token_manager class? Do you have any class defined in your token_manager.dart? Can you show some code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your new code at the bottom.

Comment: You should not wrap your code in a class. Please remove the first line `class TokenManager {` and the last line `}` from your code. Did you see my code? There is no class in it.

Comment: I'm rolling back your question to its original state so that future readers will benefit.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data to getCari method by create object fromGetCari() class
 see this

```
class GetToken {
  String token;
  Future<Null> getData() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.39:7070/api/v2/token";
    http.post(url, body: {
      "grant_type": "string",
      "branchcode": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "username": "string",
      "dbname": "string",
      "dbuser": "string",
      "dbpassword": "string",
      "dbtype": "string"
    }).then((response) {
      print("Response Status: ${response.statusCode}");
      //print("Response Body: ${response.body}");
      print('access token is -> ${json.decode(response.body)['access_token']}');
      token = json.decode(response.body)['access_token'];
      GetCari().getCari("fdfd");
    });
  }
}

class GetCari{

  getCari(String token) async {
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.39:7070/api/v2/ARPs",
        headers: {HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: token});

    if(response.statusCode ==200){
      return Cari.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else{
      throw Exception("Failed to Load");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service manager like [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to reuse values anywhere in your app.

1. Create the class that will hold your shared information

   ```
   class GetToken{
     String token;
     ...
   }
   ```
2. In your main.dart file, setup your GetIt instance

   ```
   final getIt = GetIt.instance;

   void setup() {
     getIt.registerSingleton<GetToken>(GetToken());
   }
   ```
3. Now, from anywhere in your app, you can call this class and get your token.

   ```
   var mytoken= getIt.get<AppModel>().token;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to get started.

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link that attempts to answer the question. Link only answers are **NOT** [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).